# Comparing array in PHP vs SQL database table

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I've been thinking for a long time but am not able to come up with an efficient solution. Currently, I have an array in PHP which is obtained by the user. It is an array of objects, and each object have 10 variables.

I need to check if this array matches the data of the SQL EXACTLY, meaning that all the variables of each object must match each other. Index doesn't matter.

1) How do I check? Right now the only way I can compare is the number of elements in array vs number of rows in database. If I want to check in-depth, do I really need to check variable by variable? Meaning if i have 10 objects, I need 10*10 variable checks?

2)The only viable solution I can think of is erasing the database table and insert the object one by one according the array, but I'm worried if there is like 100 objects, won't it be too heavy for the sql database?

Comment: Define "the data of the SQL". Are you talking about multiple rows? One row?

Comment: Do you want to compare or to have the data from mysql equal to the data from the array? Because both are different, really!

Comment: OK My question is not clear enough. I'll make it simpler, lets say I have an SQL table with name, level, and status. I have an array of objects with name, level, and status in php as well. I want the entire table of data to be equal to the array in php

Comment: I think your design is not good. and/Or your question is also not very clear. Only I can suggest here is instead of querying table 10 times for each variable, fetch all values from table once and compare using PHP. This will be better and faster.

Comment: removed the iphone tag since the question is not iphone related.

Answer (score 0):

A relatively primitive way would be:

```
$fields = array();

$object = new STDClass();
$object->name = "My Name";
$object->status = "My Status";
$object->level = "My Level";

foreach ($object as $key => $value)
 {
   $fields[]="`$key` = '$value'";
  }

$sql = implode(" AND ", $fields);

$query = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE $sql";
```

this would generate a query that checks for a row with exactly the values in your object.

How exact this is depends on your table's collation and character set. You can always do a `BINARY` comparison if you need 100% exact results.